# can't call __add__ through __getattr__( __getattribute__ )

Tags: python

It is object of the class A, in container's class tmpA. Not all method
from A are in the tmpA. So for example:
 A + B is present , tmpA + B isn't present. I try to call method from A for tmpA. I
 can to call simple method,  such as change(), but `__add__` -  don't
 work. If to remove inheritance from object, the code works.

```
#--------------------------------------
class A(object):
    def __init__( self, x, y ):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        pass
#-------    
    def __add__( self, arg ):
       tmp1 = self.x + arg.x
       tmp2 = self.y + arg.y
       return tmpA( A( tmp1, tmp2 ) )

    def change( self, x, y ):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        pass
    pass
#------------------------------------------
class tmpA( object ):
    def __init__( self, theA ):
        self.A = theA
        pass
#-------   
    def _print ( self ):
        print "    x =", self.A.x
        print "    y =", self.A.y
        pass
#-------
    def __call__( self ):
        return self.A
#-------   
    def __coerce__( self, *args ):
        return None

#-------
    def __getattr__( self, *args ):
        name = args[ 0 ]
        try:
            attr = None
            exec "attr = self.__call__().%s" % name
            return attr
        except :
            raise AttributeError

#--------------------------------------
class B( object ):
    def __init__( self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        pass
#-------------------------------------
a=A( 1,2 );
b=B( 3,4 );
tmp_a = a + b;  

tmp_a.change( 0, 0 ) # very well

v = tmp_a + b  #TypeError: "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'tmpA' and 'B'"
```

Answer (score 7):

Special methods are looked up **on the class**, that is, **not** on the *instance* of the class (except for some irregularities in old-style classes, which just mean a huge headache).  So in particular the class's `__getattr__` (for sane, new-style classes) is **not** getting called to look up `__add__` when a `+` is performed - the metaclass's (`type`'s, here) `__getattr__` is.

"Removing inheritance from `object`" means popping right back into the hellzapoppin world of old-style classes and only stores up pain for the future: **don't**!  Rather, if you have a class that must delegate some special methods, code them explicitly in the class (directly or via a class decorator), or make a custom metaclass that knows about this quirk (the metaclass's `__getattr__`, or other means, can then perform the task you crave).

Answer (score 2):

I think `X + Y` is taken as `X.__add__(Y)`.

So if you use

`class tempA(A)` then `temp_a + b` works because it ***inherits*** `__add__` method and uses it like `temp_a.__add__(b)`.

but if you use

`class tempA(object)` then it does not have `__add__` method in `class tempA` to call when it encounters `temp_a + b`.

Comment: Thank you very much to all. 
Really, tmp_a.__add__( b ) work's, but I can't write so.

Answer (score 1):

When you say `tmp_a + b`, Python looks in `tmp_a.__class__.__dict__` and then `object.__dict__` for the `__add__` method (bypassing the hasattr/getattr type lookup)

Since it is not found anywhere, Python then looks to see if `b` has an `__radd__` method that can handle `tmp_a` as the other parameter. Since it can't, the exception is thrown.

You will have to add a bunch of special methods to tmpA to get those to work properly.